Video codec for 3D volumetric video datasets
I have 3D volumetric MRI scans representing a time series. So the sequence of these 3D volumes presents a video composed of voxels rather than the conventional 2D pixels from traditional 2D videos. But I noticed that 2D or RGB videos have several codecs available at their disposal to compress the video so it can be efficiently stored and viewed during playback. However, I am in search of the 3D equivalent and was not able to find a video codec for voxel data. The closest I have come is info on 3D volume compression, but not on 3D video volume compression (https://eisenwave.github.io/voxel-compression-docs/). The other althernative is to use python with zarr arrays and store the N-dimensional array in appropriate sized chunks with the available numcodec compression algorithms. Is the recommended approach to individually compress each volume or are there better approaches to storing 3D video data?
